# Delete an entry from a table once it's been there for more than x days

Tags: mysql, date, time

I have a system where you can get something for "free" but only once every 7 days, I'm currently having an issue in that *once every 7 days* part.

What I want to do is delete entries in a certain table once that one or more entry/entries went over 7 days. The concerned table has an ID, USERNAME and DATE column.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as:

```
delete from theTable where date < now() - interval 7 days;
```

Make sure to run it often enough so that you don't have to delete to many rows.
If you're in an environment without replication you can go ahead and add a limit

```
delete from theTable where date < now() - interval 7 days limit 1000;
```

And if this is a large table put an index on date (or where date is first) so it doesn't do a table scan.

Comment: @Swaly: The query above deletes all entries from the table that are older than 7 days. Put that in an event that runs daily and your done